# FTP server (VSFTP) "write_enable=YES" configuration per user

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

I'm configuring an FTP server on an embedded Linux system. Iv'e set in my `/etc/passwd` a number of local users, for example:

```
UserA:14:50:FTP User A:/somepath:/bin/sh
UserB:1000:0:FTP User B:/somepath:/bin/sh
```

Problem is that I don't now how to set `write_enable` (whether any FTP commands which change the file system are allowed or not) per user. I want that `UserA` will be able to write and `UserB` not.
Example `local.vsftpd.conf`:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
userlist_deny=YES
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/UNI/System/Config/deny_vsftpd_user_list.conf
listen=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
xferlog_enable=YES
vsftpd_log_file=/tmp/vsftpd.log
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
write_enable=YES
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in this [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=72117). Here an extract of my '/etc/vsftpd.conf':

```
# This powerful option allows the override of any config option specified
# in the manual page, on a per-user basis. Usage is simple, and is best
# illustrated with an example. If you set user_config_dir to be /etc/vsftpd_user_conf
# and then log on as the user "chris", then vsftpd will apply the settings
# in the file /etc/vsftpd_user_conf/chris for the duration of the session.
# Default: (none)
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-user-conf
```

Each time a new ftp virtual user need a personal ftp directory, under the dir '/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-user-conf' I create a file named as the username where I define the personal ftp directory and the auth on it (RO or RW).
Example for user 'test' (file '/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-user-conf/test'):

```
# vsftpd per-user basis config file (override of any config option specified
# in the vsftpd server config file)
#
# TEMPLATE
#
# User test - Description for user test
#

# Set local root
local_root=/srv/vsftpd/test

# Disable any form of FTP write command.
# Allowed values: YES/NO
write_enable=YES
```

Answer (score 1):

Set permissions on filesystem.

```
chown -R userA /somepath
chmod -R 755 /somepath
```